# Hotkey shortcut key issue in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder, shortcut

On my keyboard, I have to press <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>G</kbd> to type `[` and `]`. However, <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>AltGr</kbd> are also hotkey buttons for shortcuts in **Spyder**. I need `[` and `]` way more than shortcuts at the moment, so is it possible to disable the these buttons as shortcut buttons?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to `Tools> Preferences> Keyboard shortcuts`, you might find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the `Ctrl+Alt+[` shortcut for `find in files`. (Windows treats Ctrl+Alt as AltGr - see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key#Control_+_Alt_as_a_substitute).)

**Go to `Tools> Preferences> Keyboard shortcuts`, and delete the shortcut for `find in files`.**